# Reversing a sentence recursively in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I want to reverse a sentence recursively and below is my following code. I wanted to know what other bases cases shud i take care of. And for the base case if string is null, how should that be handled?

```
public String reverse(String s) {
int n = s.indexOf(' ');
if(n == -1)
    return s;
return reverse(s.substring(n+1))+" "+s.substring(0,n);

}
```

Comment: Will you need to handle multiple spaces or tabs between words, and what are your rules for  mid-sentence and end of sentence punctuation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse of `null` is `null`, so that's easy:

```
if(s == null) return null;
```

Because your method has the potential to return `null`, then, I would also do some null checking before referencing the value in your `return` statement and trying to append to it.  so, something like...

```
String reversed = reverse(s.substring(n+1));
if(reversed != null) return reverse + " " + s.substring(0,n);
else return s;
```

Everything else looks fine. You shouldn't need any other base cases.  Of course, this will reverse the sentence exactly as-is, including punctuation and case information.  If you want to do this kind of thing, more strenuous processing will be required.

To ensure appropriate upper- and lower-case structure, I'd probably do something like this in your normal base case:

```
if(n == -1) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    String firstLetter = new String(s.charAt(0));
    s = s.replaceFirst(firstLetter, firstLetter.toUpperCase());
    return s;
}
```

Punctuation gets a little more complicated, especially if you have more than just an ending period, exclamation point, or question mark.

Comment: like FordFulkerson suggested, can i return empty string ("") for the case if (s==null)??

Comment: Sure you can.  It might be slightly misleading in some cases, since if I'm calling this method from the outside, I would expect the reverse of `""` to be `""` and the reverse of `null` to be `null`, but this is just a little nitpick and something theory-based, since `null != ""`.  You're free to implement it however you choose, and returning `""` will still reverse normal Strings just fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

in your case, if the string is null, you can return an empty string (""). Returning a null will require you to handle the null in the calling functions and if you miss a case, you might encounter a NullPointerException